# Add action admin_post_nopriv_ not working in custom roles - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="createsnew_form" />
    <input type="text" name="newtitle" id="newtitle" placeholder="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Create New" />
</form>
```

In my function.php

```
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_createsnew_form', 'addnewpostsform' );
add_action( 'admin_post_createsnew_form', 'addnewpostsform' );
function addnewpostsform()
{
    if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == "createsnew_form" )
    {
        $post_type = 'custom_post_type';
        $title = $_POST['newtitle'];
        $new_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',          
        'post_type'     => $post_type,
        );
        $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
        wp_safe_redirect(esc_url(home_url('/')) . "thank-you/");
        exit();
    }
}
```

I create a custom role "Brand", when a user (role brand) login to the site and try to create a new post this code is not working. But a user is login with administrator privilege this code works. Is there any issue with my code.
When i submit the form it redirect to home page.

Comment: Does your custom role have permission to edit / create posts ? Install https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/ and see what permissions you have. Could you please share your role setup ?

Comment: I am using Members plugin, i allowed permission to edit / create posts

Comment: admin_post_nopriv_createsnew_form means not loggedin users are allowed to create post (visitors). I have tested without loggedin , loggedin as admin , loggedin as custom role and your code is working.

Comment: I don't know what happened in my side.